# how to add product from external page into virtuemart while click on some button

Tags: virtuemart

I am trying to add a product directly to cart which is in virtuemart from external page. I have one external page there I have a button.

When we click on that button, the product details should go to cart in virtuemart and it should not affect the virtuemart add to cart functionality.

What should I do to make it possible. If you know the answer help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question, i have implemented this concept in one of my custom component page. you can use it anywhere only you have to provide product id and quantity.
following is the code you have to implement to your page:

**Dont forget to change the variable in following div:**

**quantity= "1"** replace 1 with your quantity

**"$res->virtuemart_product_id"** replace it with your product id

**Place the following div inside your page:**

```
<div class="addtocart-bar">
  <span class="addtocart-button" style="float:right !important;"> 
    <input type="submit" url='<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS&format=json&lang=en&quantity=1&quantity%5B%5D=1&view=cart&virtuemart_product_id%5B%5D=$res->virtuemart_product_id&option=com_virtuemart"); ?>' title="Add to Cart" value="Add to Cart" id="btn_addtocart" class="bttn right" name="addtocart">
  </span>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**and at the top of page you have to add following code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("[name=addtocart]").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('url');

            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: url,
                async:false,
                data:{'p_id' : 1 },
                success: function(html){
                    var msg ="<div id='fancybox-content'><div style='width:auto;height:auto;overflow: auto;position:relative;'><div class='popUp_Box'><p>This item has been added to your shopping cart.</p><a class='continue bttn rmv_brdr btn_fix' href='index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=categories&virtuemart_category_id=0'>Keep Shopping</a><?php if($user->id){ ?><a href='index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart' class='showcart floatright bttn btn_fix'>Check Out</a><?php }else{ ?><a href='index.php?option=com_users&view=login&checkout=1' class='showcart floatright bttn btn_fix'>Check Out</a><?php } ?></div></div></div><a id='fancybox-close' style='display: block;'></a>";

                    jQuery.fancybox({
                                "titlePosition" :   "inside",
                                "transitionIn"  :   "elastic",
                                "transitionOut" :   "elastic",
                                "type"          :   "html",
                                "autoCenter"    :   true,
                                "closeBtn"      :   true,
                                "closeClick"    :   false,
                                "content"       :   msg
                            }
                        );

                }
            });
    });

    });
</script>
```

The Above Script will work if you have fancybox plugin saved at your root folder, for that please download fancybox plugin from "http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license". I have used fancybox because when the order is added to cart your order confirmation will appear in fancybox, that looks great. i am also attaching one of the image to show where you have to add fancybox plugin folder. I hope this will help you a lot.

[image: Place fancybox plugin folder at this position.]

Regards

Mohit :)